# android: how to stop and start a thread (with buggy code example)

Tags: android, multithreading

I tried to create a thread in app. Here is the code:

```
private class GetFileTask extends Thread {
    private volatile boolean mKeepRunning = false;
    public GetFileTask() {
        super("GetFileTask");         
    }
    /** Cancel task */
    public void cancel() {
        mKeepRunning = false;
        interrupt();
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        mKeepRunning = true;
        while (true) {
            try {
              doTask();
              Sleep(300);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if (!mKeepRunning) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    private void doTask() {
    }    
}
```

I tried to let the user to cancel download (cancel the thread), and later on, start to download from zero again ( restart the thread). I read android sdk doc, and I know I should not use pause/suspend. I tried to cancel the thread by calling `cancel();` and tried to restart the thread by calling `run();`
However, my app hang when I called `run();`

So, based on above code sample, what is the correct way to `stop` and `restart` a thread?

Comment: I dont see why the app should hang. Unless doTask is doing something silly.

Answer (score 2):

You should call GetFileTask.start() which will cause the run() method to be executed in the thread.

Calling GetFileTask.run() directly merely executes that code on the calling thread, which is not what you want, as the Sleep() (and time required for the task itself) would then block the calling thread.

Edit: note that it is not legal to call start() a second time on the same instance of your thread.

Comment: I think i have stopped the run() by calling cancel(), so the while loop is broken. so the thread is not at sleep when I call run() again.

Comment: You are not supposed to call run() at all

Comment: @ChrisStratton agreed. he should call `GetFileTask.start()` Also he is calling `sleep` in which case interrupt status will be cleared and it will receive an `InterruptedException`. So calling `interrupted()` will return true?. So will it receive `InterruptedException`?.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupted(). the doc cleared my doubt.

Comment: @Raghunandan - the poster is not interrupting the thread, but rather signalling it by negating the volatile flag variable mKeepRunning so that that it will exit the while loop.  However, according to the document you linked it is not legal to call start() a second time.

Comment: @ChrisStratton agreed. yup read the docs both java and android.

Comment: so, how can i suspend a thread and resume it on later time?? it seems this problem is very difficult....thanks a lot for help.

Comment: Have it wait on something in kernel context until you indicate that you have more work for it.   Or make a new thread.  Or use one of the mechanisms for assigning tasks to threads.